# Detect if AMD CPU has modules

Tags: assembly, x86, intrinsics, amd-processor, cpuid

Some Intel CPUs have hyper-threading which I can detect by reading [bit 28 in register EDX from CPUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID). AMD CPUs don't have hyper-threading but some of them have  [modules which have two integer units and one floating point unit](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3863/a...t-chips-2010/4). Is there a way, such as through CPUID, to detect if a CPU has modules?

Edit: based on Jester's answer I have come up with the following untested function (I don't have access to an AMD processor) to determine the number of cores per "compute unit" (aka module).

```
// input:  eax = functionnumber, ecx = 0
// output: eax = output[0], ebx = output[1], ecx = output[2], edx = output[3]
//static inline void cpuid (int output[4], int functionnumber)  

void coresPerComputeUnit() {
    int abcd[4];
    int cores = 1;
    cpuid(abcd,0x80000000);
    if(abcd[0]<0x8000001E) return; // Fn8000_001E not available 
    cpuid(abcd,0x8000001E);  
    cores += (abcd[1] & 0xff00) >> 8; //ebx bit 15:8 CoresPerComputeUnit
}
```

http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/42301_15h_Mod_00h-0Fh_BKDG1.pdf

Comment: This isn't complete enough to answer your question, but section E5 (Multiple Core Calculation) in [the AMD architecture programmer's manual volume 3](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2008/10/24594_APM_v3.pdf) mentions how to find out how many cores a processor has. As [Bulldozer is a microarchitecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldozer_%28microarchitecture%29), rather than an architecture itself, this may be the best you can do to find out if an AMD processor looks like it's using Bulldozer. (The manual I linked has no instances of "Bulldozer", at least.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cpuid Fn8000_001E Compute Unit Identifiers.
Bits 15:8 of `EBX` (ie. `BH`) holds *CoresPerComputeUnit: cores per compute unit. Value: Product-specific. The number of cores per compute unit is CoresPerComputeUnit+1.*

See the AMD Bios and Kernel Developer's Guide.

Comment: I added some untested code to do this.  I'm not really sure about checking the availability of Fn8000_001E.  I don't have and AMD system to test this on.

Comment: Works fine on my FX-8350.

Comment: You tested my function and it gives cores = 2?

Comment: Thanks for checking this!